# Logging into facebook via java URLConnection

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a java application and I want it to be able to login and go to my wall (only my wall) and a few groups to see if anything new has been posted. This is not production code. This is just for me. The problem is that I can't figure out how to login while using a URLConnection. You can see open facebook groups if you aren't logged in. But you have to be logged in to see closed groups and I want to be able to see those too. This is not a web app. This is just making a connection and pulling down the html and then parsing through it.

My friend says facebook has an OAuth thing for this purpose but after reading around the internet it seems like the OAuth is for logging in your application or for logging in a client and verifying them and maybe posting to their wall. But maybe I am just doing this the complete wrong way and should be using oauth and the graph api or something...

Anyway, I tried building a URLConnection and making a request to facebook, saving all the cookies, and then tried constructing a new connection with all the headers and whatnot to login to facebook but it knows that it isn't an actual user but an automated program and isn't working. Anybody know how I might be able to get authenticated?

```
String cookies = "";
URL myUrl = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/");
URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
urlConn.connect();
String headerName=null;
for (int i=1; (headerName = urlConn.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
    if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {                  
       String cookie = urlConn.getHeaderField(i);    
       cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
       String cookieName = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("="));
       String cookieValue = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.length());
       cookies = cookies+cookieName+"="+cookieValue+"; ";
       cookieNameList.add(cookieValue);
    }
}    
URL url = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
conn.setRequestProperty("accept-encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
conn.setRequestProperty("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
conn.setRequestProperty("cache-control", "max-age=0");
conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("accepts-encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
conn.setRequestProperty("accept-encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
conn.setRequestProperty("accept-encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
String query = "lsd=AVpGDi9X&email=xxxxxxxx%40gmail.com&pass=xxxxxxxxx&persistent=1&default_persistent=1&timezone=360&lgnrnd=135940_imAl&lgnjs=1375995581&locale=en_US";
OutputStream output = null;

try {
    output = conn.getOutputStream();
    output.write(query.getBytes("UTF-8"));
} finally {
     if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
try{
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  String line;
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
  }
  rd.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print("URL BROKE!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its somewhat confusing when you start out.  I will assume you do NOT want to automate the process of typing your fb password into a web page.  In that case, you do want to use OAuth to authorize your application to access your fb account - without your app having to know your fb password.  In that case, you would start here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/

For this to work, your program either has to be able to show a browser window, or you instruct the user to visit the auth URL and provide the token result back to your program

Comment: I updated the description a little bit. This isn't a web app or anything this is just a small java program that I am running from my computer. I am trying to hardcode in my username and password which is fine. I just want to scrape a bunch of facebook pages looking for keywords.

Answer (score 0):

you must add this line:

```
conn.setRequestMethod("post");
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication can do what you want here. Apache common client is good api for that. I tried it long ago. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2092353/core-java/httpclient-basic-authentication.html